# Is it possible to create a presto table using binary serialized objects as data format?

Tags: java, serialization, presto

I am quite new on Presto and want to create some tables. My files are serialized objects and would like to know if I can skip the conversion to `Parquet/ORC/CSV` or another format by creating the table to read serialized java objects

I have not tried anything

```
CREATE [EXTERNAL] TABLE 
 mydb.ser_objs [(col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment] [, ...] )]
 ROW FORMAT row_format
 STORED AS (JAVA CLASS or something?)
 LOCATION 'myloc'
```

Comment: There is nothing in Presto supporting this and I think there might be no Hive SerDe for this either. (Also, I'd discourage Java serialization as a storage format due to potential security issues.)

Comment: The Presto engine is very flexible, and with a lot of work you could likely write a new Hive file format to read the data, but you would also need to write new Presto SQL types and functions to process the data.  I agree with Piotr's suggestion to not use Java Object Serialization as a storage format.